# Map a JSON array to a LongListSelector of Images

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, json.net, json-deserialization

I recently started working with JSON data in C#/XAML for a Windows Phone 8 app. 
I have successfully parsed and mapped simple JSON data types to LongListSelector so far. Even after reading so many answers and posts for many hours, I haven't solved this particular problem yet.

Now I encountered a JSON of type this:

```
{
    "images":
    [
        "http://motoroids.com/Honda-Logo.png",
        "htt//somelink0/1.png",
        "htt//somelink1/2.png",
        "htt//somelink2/3.png"
    ]
}
```

I want to show these images in LongListSelector defined like this:

```
<phone:LongListSelector Name="sponsorlist" ItemsSource="{Binding images}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="504" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="436">
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="10 10 10 10">
                            <Image Source="{Binding ????}" Height="219" Width="153" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>
```

Here is the class for JSON data:

```
public class RootObject
        {
            public List<string> images { get; set; }
        }
```

To parse it I use to the Json.Net nuget package like this:

```
var sponsfile = ReadFile(@"Assets/sponsors.txt");
RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(sponsfile);
sponsorlist.DataContext = obj;
```

I can't understand what should I write in the place of ???? to show the images. 
This is my first question, please point out any flaws, I'll try to provide more information if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to bind the current element.
So just edit the image binding as follows:

```
<Image Source="{Binding}" Height="219" Width="153" />
```